# export value of checkboxes to excel in jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) pluging to view some data and I have in my table two columns containing checkboxes, I've tried to export the data from the table to an XSLX file using [excel](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel) and [excelHtml5](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) and also excelFlash buttons but I get two empty columns in the file, I've also included JSZip plugin in my project but in vain. How can I get the values of these checkboxes as booleans in my file.

Comment: Can you please create an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: okay ! just a few minutes and I'll share the example with you

Comment: Here is it : http://jsfiddle.net/neozak/bqwnaekL/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### SOLUTION

You're using DataTables 1.10.8. Before this version (1.10.7 and earlier) there was TableTools with [`fnCellRender`](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#fnCellRender) option that would help to do what you want. Since 1.10.8 TableTools extension has been replaced with Buttons extension.

With Buttons extension you may use [`exportOptions`](http://datatables.net/reference/button/excel#Options) and tell DataTables that you want the the data used for sorting (`orthogonal: 'sort'`). Then you need to define [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function and return appropriate data when sorting is performed (`type === 'sort'`).

```js
/*
 * Create an array with the values of all the checkboxes in a column 
 */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function (settings, col) {
    return this.api()
        .column(col, { order: 'index' })
        .nodes()
        .map(function (td, i) {
            return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
        });
};

var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
    dom : 'Bfrtlip',    
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                orthogonal: 'sort'
            }
        }        
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
       targets:[0,5],
       orderDataType: 'dom-checkbox',
       render: function(data, type, row, meta){
          if(type === 'sort'){
             var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( meta.settings );
             var $input = $(api.cell({ row: meta.row, column: meta.col }).node()).find('input');
             data = $input.prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
          }
           
          return data;    
       }
    }]
});

table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( $('.col-sm-6:eq(0)', table.table().container() ) );
```

### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5gn6jwv/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Great solution using native functions.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a proper solution. Once you change the checkboxes the values are not aligned any more.

Comment: @FrankyBoy, it's been fixed, thanks for reporting.